# Strings inside a multi-dimensional array don't have terminating NUL character?

Tags: c, string

I tried to print every strings of a multi-dimensional array, but it seemed to me that these strings had no NUL character (`'\0'`).

Here is the code that I used:

```
int main(void)
{
    char    test[3][2] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'};

    printf("'%s'\n", test[0]);
    printf("'%s'\n", test[1]);
    printf("'%s'\n", test[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is the following:

```
'123456'
'3456'
'56'
```

Declaring it this way would result in the same output:

```
char    test[3][2] = {"12", "34", "56"};
```

I had to put a NUL character by myself after each string:

```
int main(void)
{
    char    test[3][3] = {'1', '2', 0, '3', '4', 0, '5', '6', 0};
    printf("'%s'\n", test[0]);
    printf("'%s'\n", test[1]);
    printf("'%s'\n", test[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

I could also declare my multi-dimensional array this way:

```
char    test[3][3] = {{'1', '2'}, {'3', '4'}, {'5', '6'}};
```

Output:

```
'12'
'34'
'56'
```

This is what I know: when declaring a string there is no need to declare the NULL-terminated character in the end of it. `str[3] = "123"` will allocate 4 slots of memory instead of 3, and put `'\0'` in the last slot.

The following link confirms it: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html

But then why would we need to manually implement a NUL character at the end of a string which is inside of an array?

Comment: That is because you are intialising with `int` values not with a `"string"`. Imagine the confusion if the compiler appended a `0` to every array of `char`!

Comment: In the first example there couldn't have been a nul-terminator anyway: not enough array length.

Comment: 'x' is not a string in C, it's an integer containing the ASCII value of x.

Comment: The correct way would have been `char test[3][3] = {"12", "34", "56"};` Now there is room for the `nul` to be appended by the compiler.

Comment: You should compile with warnings enabled: http://ideone.com/JVrEjX

Comment: A string literal includes a terminating `'\0'`  (e.g. `"AB"` is actually represented as an array of three characters, with the third being a `'\0'`).   Your first code sample code is using six non-zero values to initialise elements of an array that has six elements - which means no zero values are stored in the array.   The compiler, reasonably, expects that you do not expect additional elements with zero value to be added.

Comment: That was because you did not leave room for the nuls, see my previous comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049003/which-is-better-way-to-initialize-array-of-characters-using-string-literal/42049017#42049017

Comment: But is there a reason for the string not to have enough room? Why a normal string has room for it and a string inside of an array has no room? Why does the allocated array doesn't let room for a nul terminator?

Comment: Yes: you did not *give* it enough room. You cannot fit 4 characters in an array of length 3, so the compiler omitted the terminator.

Comment: I don't give normal strings enough room neither to contain a nul terminator

Comment: `char str[3] = "123";` is equivalent to `char str[3] = { '1', '2', 3' };`. There is no null terminator there. But `char str[] = "123";` is equivalent to `char str[4] = { '1', '2', '3', '\0' };`, relying on automatic dimensioning of the array.

Comment: i just don't get why the room for the nul terminator must be manually given for a string inside of an array, but not for a normal string

Comment: What do you mean by a "normal string"? One whose dimension is determined automatically?

Comment: If a "normal" string is `string[3] = "abc"` there will be no nul terminator becasue you told the compiler the array must be of length 3. If it is `string[] = "abc"` the compiler automatically sizes the array to the required length

Comment: i'm talking about a string that is not inside of an array. like when you declare `str[3] = "123"`

Comment: .... but in a 2-D array where the data might not all be the same length, you *must* define the inner dimension so the compiler can figure out the indexing.

Comment: As I mentioned above `char str[3] = "123";` has no null terminator.

Comment: okkkk well that's my answer I understand now ty for your answers

Comment: @George: `str[3] = "123";` is very well defined. The resulting `str` is not a string though, as it is missing the zero terminator. Passing it to functions accepting a string invokes **UB**, not creating it.

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
char    test1[3][2] = { "1", "3", "5" };
```

and

```
char    test2[3][3] = { "12", "34", "56" };
```

will work.

If you surround one or more charactors with a pair of quotation mark("), the compiler will know you have declared a string and it will always assign an extra '\0' in the end of the string, consuming one extra byte memory space. That's why we always declare array that has one extra byte's space for a known usage, e.g. using array `char sz[6]` to store string "hello".

On the other hand, if you surround one charactor with a pair of single quotation mark('), e.g. `'a'`, it will be considered as an ordinary value, same as `int nNum`. The only difference between `'a'` and `nNum` is the memory consumption (`'a'` is 1 byte and `nNum` is 4 bytes). We can mix the two in one calculation without forcedly type transfer, e.g.

```
int nNum = 1; 
nNum = nNum + 'a';
```

This will add 97 (the ascii value of charactor 'a') to `nNum` itself, turning `nNum` into 98. If you go on printing `nNum` out like this:

```
 printf("%c", nNum);
```

You will get charactor `'b'` printed out.

Comment: Note that there is no partial initialization in C. `char x[9] = { 'A' };` will write zeroes to `x[1]`  to `x[8]`.

Comment: In C, the type of `'a'` is `int` (things may be different in another language). Try printing `sizeof 'a'`.

Comment: @pmg I tried printing `sizeof 'a'` in Visual Studio 2015, and the output was 1. Nevertheless, in Debug mode of VS 2015, a char variable does occupy 4 bytes of memory space. Things may differ with different compliers.

Comment: Try `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error wrong compiler` / `#endif`